# What does "++=" mean in Scala

Tags: scala

This is the [implementation](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableLike.scala) of `flatMap` in Scala

```
def flatMap[B, That](f: A => GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That = {
  def builder = bf(repr) // ...
  val b = builder
  for (x <- this) b ++= f(x).seq
  b.result
}
```

What does `++=` mean here ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`++=` can mean two different things in Scala:

1: Invoke the `++=` method

In your example with `flatMap`, the `++=` method of `Builder` takes another collection and adds its elements into the builder. Many of the other mutable collections in the Scala collections library define a similiar `++=` method.

2: Invoke the `++` method and replace the contents of a `var`

`++=` can also be used to invoke the `++` method of an object in a `var` and replace the value of the `var` with the result:

```
var l = List(1, 2)
l ++= List(3, 4)
// l is now List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

The line `l ++= List(3, 4)` is equivalent to `l = l ++ List(3, 4)`.

Answer (score 5):

Note that `++=` is a method, not a part of the Scala language.  If it is defined for a particular class, then it has whatever meaning that class defines it to have.  In this case it means "add these to the end."

Also note that if a class defines `++` but not `++=` then the compiler will treat

```
x ++= y
```

as

```
x = x ++ y
```

this is true generally for symbols ending in an equal sign (other than `==`, `!=`, and `=`, of course).  This syntactic sugar allows immutable and mutable variants of the same data structure to be used in a consistent way.

Answer (score 1):

[The API of Builder](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.mutable.Builder) says:

> adds all elements produced by a TraversableOnce to this growable collection.